# How to access viewmodel in normal class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I Have a view model and i want to access all the properties value in another class which is not a viewmodel. So how to pass whole viewmodel as a parameter into another class method or is there some other way to do this thing? 
i wantto achieve something like below

```
Public Class ViewModel
{
  var res = XYZClass.ExecuteAsync(ViewModel);
}

 Public Static Class XYZClass{
     public Static Task ExecuteAsync(ViewModel request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Comment: use this instead of ViewModel. `var res = XYZClass.ExecuteAsync(this);`

Comment: Thanks, it works. is this a good approach to access data?

Comment: This is the way to access a class from itself

Answer (score 0):

Put in a public static property reference to the instantiated view model on the app class. Then it can be accessed it from any other class.

I worked on a Silverlight project which did that very thing with the VM and other *globally* shared data.